# How can I permanently display a navigation bar in reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

In (quarto) reveal.js, how can I permanently display a navigation bar on the left side, created automatically from the headings, and use it as a link to the slides? Ideally, only the subheadings of the current chapter are displayed.

I would like to switch from LaTeX-Beamer to quarto-reveal.js because I want to embed more and more code and interactive elements in my slides.  However, my students appreciate the structure overview on the side, also because they can quickly find content passages (e.g. "Vorgehen" means procedure) in the podcast videos. Here's an example, with the navigation bar on the left from Beamer:
[image]

The wide screen format provides a lot of width space, in my opinion. Basically, we have too much space in width and not enough in height relative to that. That's why I don't want to put the whole outline in the footer or header.

I have tried menu from reveal.js, but I'm looking for a navigation bar that doesn't disappear, doesn't overlap with the slides and doesn't darken them.

```
---
title: "Quarto Markdown"
format: 
  revealjs:
    navigation-mode: vertical
    number-sections: true
    menu: 
      sticky: true
      keyboard: true
      autoOpen: true
      width: normal
---


# Quarto

## Why

Quarto® is an open-source scientific and technical publishing system built on Pandoc

## What is Quarto?

-   Quarto is the successor for Markdown and RMarkdown
-   Quarto/Markdown is a simple, readable plain text language
```